# how to use the breakpoint feature in Angular using the Swiper Element

Tags: html, angular, breakpoints, swiper.js

I want to know how to use the breakpoint feature in Angular using the Swiper Element. Thank you

I tried hard to find a solution to this problem, but I could not. This is my first time here. I hope to find a solution to this problem

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.